OutOfMemoryException in .NET 8 Applications on IIS with EF core
I have a problem with memory management in my API applications hosted on IIS. The server runs 40 applications, a mix of .NET Framework 4.8 and .NET 8. The problem is that .NET 8 applications consume memory and don't release it back to the operating system effectively.
Although the Garbage Collector (GC) is running, the memory often remains allocated within the process as free memory but is not returned to the OS. This behavior leads to high memory usage across processes, and some applications eventually throw OutOfMemoryException.
Additionally, before the GC runs, Generation 0 often grows to significant sizes, sometimes reaching hundreds of megabytes or even several gigabytes. This excessive memory usage is causing major performance issues, and I need a solution to optimize memory usage, force .NET 8 applications to release unused memory more effectively, and mitigate these problems.
The applications are using EF Core 8.0.11 (only reading). DbContext is registered as scoped.
I tested it with new .NET 8 application with one single controller
[Route("/api/test")]
public class TestController(IDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext> dbContextFactory) : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("GetSpeakers")]
    public List<Speaker> GetSpeakers()
    {
        using var dbContext = dbContextFactory.CreateDbContext();
        return dbContext.Speakers.AsNoTracking().OrderBy(s => s.Name).ThenBy(s => s.Id).ToList();
    }
}

Program.cs:
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services
    .AddDbContextPool<ApplicationDbContext>(
        options => options.UseSqlServer("Server=localhost;Database=TestDb;Trusted_Connection=True;TrustServerCertificate=True;"))
    .AddPooledDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext>(
        options => options.UseSqlServer("Server=localhost;Database=TestDb;Trusted_Connection=True;TrustServerCertificate=True;"));


var app = builder.Build();

app.UseRouting();
app.MapControllers();

app.Run();

Packages:
<PropertyGroup>
  <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
  <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  <RootNamespace>TestApi</RootNamespace>
  <NoWarn>GD0001</NoWarn>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="8.0.11" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="8.0.11">
    <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
  </PackageReference>
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational" Version="8.0.11" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="8.0.11" />
</ItemGroup>

I had 200 elements in speakers table, I call the endpoint many times and observe memory usage in dot memory.
public sealed class Speaker
{
    public int Id { get; init; }

    [StringLength(200)]
    public required string Name { get; init; }

    [StringLength(4000)]
    public string? Bio { get; init; }

    [StringLength(1000)]
    public string? Website { get; init; }
}

After GC:

Do you have any recommendations for improving memory management or configuring the GC to better handle this scenario? Or mayble some code in my app is wrong.

"The server runs 40 applications" sounds like a bad idea. Have you tried configuring GC to use server mode and other settings? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/runtime-config/garbage-collector It also looks from that screenshot that your main issue is actually Unmanaged Memory, which indicates some kind of native-side memory leak. What native libraries are you using that would cause this? Ultimately we can't solve this as we don't have your system in front of us. There are simply too many things it could be.

Why does 40 applications sound like a bad idea? Each website has its own app pool.
I tried with GC parameters:
"System.GC.ConserveMemory": (5-9)
"System.GC.HighMemoryPercent": (40-90)
"System.GC.Aggressive": true
"System.GC.EnableFullBlockingCollection": true
"System.GC.Server": (true/false)
However, these adjustments did not yield positive results. For now, I have set up periodic app pool recycling to prevent memory shortages.

the issue occurs when too many large strings are loaded, https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/34365
